# Retroactively change non-SSL enabled HNSC web application to enable SSL/HTTPS

Tags: 2013, ssl, https, host-named

I have a SharePoint 2013 system and have a Host Named Site Collection (HNSC) web application.  When the web application was first created, we didn't enable SSL parameter (-SecureSocketsLayer).  Is it possible to retroactively change the web application and enable SSL without deleting and recreating everything?

A workaround might be to extend the web app and setup AAM, but if possible, we would like to simply enable SSL within the existing HNSC web app.

Answer (score 0):

https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/sharepoint-2013-host-named-site-collections-over-ssl-2/

I was able to manually setup HTTPS in IIS and then added via Set-SPSiteURL using the article above.

I'm not sure if this will then allow me to change the default from HTTP to HTTPS, but I'll ultimately try.